# vertices of a lattice polygon with n sides

Tags: algorithms, polygons

is there a pattern that can be followed to draw a polygon which should be symmetrical both horizontally and vertically and the co-ordinates of vertices should be integers. considering that the vertices are on lattice points, the internal angles should be either 45 or 90 or 135. so based on this how to find a algorithm to find vertices if number of sides is given.

Comment: The only non-degenerate polygons with those internal angles are a 45-45-90 triangle and a rectangle (or square).

Comment: Yes just realised that. There's an option of 135 too

Comment: That still only gives you convex polygons. The largest number of sides/vertices you can get is 8, which happens when all angles are 135.